# RabbitMQ stomp protocol, differences between destinations

Tags: spring, websocket, rabbitmq, stomp, spring-websocket

I'm writing a Websockets app, using Spring Websockets API based on stomp protocol.

I'm using RabbitMQ as my Stomp broker, as you know when you use a different broker rather than the simple one the destinations getting different meanings.

In other words, my question is what are the differences and when to use:

```
/topic, /queue, /exchange, /app, /user
```

I already watched this webinar: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mmIza3L64Ic&t=94s

and already cloned this sample: https://github.com/rstoyanchev/spring-websocket-portfolio

but still, it's not clear enough.